# Entity Framework Code first migration creates incorrect tables and columns?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to migration a a C# model, and don't understand the tables and columns that EF6 end up creating.

This is the database models I want

[image]

and for that purpose have I defined these 3 c# models

```
public class Owner
{
    [Required]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class House
{
    [Required]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("owner")]
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("resident")]
    public IEnumerable<Resident>? Resident { get; set; }
}

public class Resident
{
    [Required]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("renter_name")]
    public string RenterName { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I end up getting when I do code first migration with EF:

[image]

I am confused on why `House` does not have a column `Renter`, which is nullable?
And why `People` has a column named `People`

Comment: House has a collection of `resident` so that cannot be modeled as a field in `House`. I don't see anything named "Renter" nor "People" so the question is missing some detail.

Comment: `[ForeignKey("resident")] public IEnumerable<Resident>? Resident { get; set; }` should be `public ICollection<Resident> Residents { get; set; } = new HashSet<Resident>();`. A collection navigation property has an upper bound of `ICollection<T>` because EF needs to be able to call `Add` on it. It should not be nullable, should have a default value, and not have a `ForeignKeyAttribute` applied to it.

Comment: Resident is ofcourse people here. 

how do i then read a house which has a owner, and no residents?

`context.House.include(x=>x.owner).include(x=>x.resident)`